# Why are some values in Sklearn K-Nearest Neighbors affinity matrix for spectral clustering equal to 0.5?

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to understand how KNN works for spectral clustering. The affinity information I am getting below have a few values being 0.5.

I added the affinity matrix to its transpose and took the average of it but there are still a few discrepancies with the result that this code gives.

I specifically want to know how the 0.5's below come about.

```
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2,0], [2, 1],
              [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7]])
sc = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='nearest_neighbors', n_neighbors=3, assign_labels='discretize', random _state=0).fit(X)
```

```
  (0, 1)    1.0
  (0, 3)    1.0
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 4)    0.5
  (1, 0)    1.0
  (1, 2)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 4)    0.5
  (2, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (3, 0)    1.0
  (3, 4)    1.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (4, 2)    0.5
  (4, 1)    0.5
  (4, 3)    1.0
  (4, 4)    1.0
  (5, 7)    1.0
  (5, 6)    1.0
  (5, 5)    1.0
  (6, 7)    1.0
  (6, 5)    1.0
  (6, 6)    1.0
  (7, 5)    1.0
  (7, 6)    1.0
  (7, 7)    1.0



I added the affinity matrix to its transpose and took the average of it but there are still a few discrepancies with the result that this code gives.
```

Comment: Hi there  In this question, it's unclear where the numbers are coming from. Are you looking at `sc.affinity_matrix_.todense()`?

Comment: Thanks for asking Alexander. I used sc.affinity_matrix_ The result is what we see below the code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get 0.5 in the affinity matrix is because of this [line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/093e0cf14aff026cca6097e8c42f83b735d26358/sklearn/cluster/_spectral.py#L705) in the implementation of `sklearn.SpectralClustering`:

```py
connectivity = estimator.kneighbors_graph(X=X, mode="connectivity")
self.affinity_matrix_ = 0.5 * (connectivity + connectivity.T)  # <-- this line
```

The matrix corresponding to the k-nearest neighbors graph is added to its transpose and then multiplied by 0.5.
Basically, this line ensures that the resulting affinity matrix is symmetric, which has nice properties when it comes to computing the eigendecomposition (the next step of spectral clustering). In particular, the resulting eigenvectors will be real and orthogonal.

To give a concrete example, consider the following matrix:

```py
>>> connectivity = np.array([[1., 0., 1.],
                             [0., 1., 1.],
                             [1., 0., 1.]])
```

Its transpose is:

```py
>>> connectivity_t = connectivity.T
array([[1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Adding these two matrices together and multiplying by 0.5 gives you:

```py
>>> 0.5 * (connectivity + connectivity_t)
array([[1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.5],
       [1., 0.5, 1.]])
```